# Dynamic dimension used in Qlik bar chart is not filtering data on selecting any bars

Tags: bar-chart, qlikview

I've created a bar chart in Qlik dashboard. Using inline load I've added static data to filters(Listbox) of my dashboard. It is unavoidable so have taken static data for filters.
Based on the item selected in filters(ListBox) by user I'm creating a dynamic dimension on qlik bar chart using actual fields from the data source. but when I click on any bar its not filtering all associated data of dashboard and even bar chart is also not filtering accordingly.

Can you please suggest any workaround for this.

Thanks

Comment: You can have a Listbox coming directly from the data source, can you clarify why you need to create static data for that purpose?

Comment: Listbox data is not present in data source. e.g. In my Data source i've A1X, A2Y ,A3Z, B1X, B2Y, B3Z, C1X, C2Y, C3Z. These columns have some meaning. There are 2 Listboxes where I'm providing list like A1, A2, A3, B1, B2,B3,C1,C2,C3 and another list with X,Y,Z. so based on combination of these 2 i've to show dynamic dimension for bar chart.

Comment: Could you use the column source A1X into two new columns (that would be used only for filtering) containing A1 (Left 2) and X (Right 1)? I'll provide an example in a response.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to split the data source column into something you could use for filtering. I'll assume that the column coming from the Data Source is named ProductCode. In the LOAD script you'll have something like :

```
LOAD
   ...
   ProductCode,
   ...
```

You could try to add two new columns like this :

```
LOAD
   ...
   ProductCode,
   Left(ProductCode, 2) as ProductCodePrefix,
   Right(ProductCode, 1) as ProductCodeSuffix,
   ...
```

Could this help?